# How to enable REST for Apache 2 under Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, http

How can I enable REST methods (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) for Apache 2 under Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

You may consider running the [Axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) engine. You may also be interested in [wso2](http://wso2.com/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, REST simply makes use of the existing HTTP protocol - so when you want to use a REST POST, at the protocol layer you're really using an HTTP POST.  That would mean that REST methods should be enabled by default on all web servers.  Now, if you want server to do anything interesting with REST calls, you'd still need to write a program to do interesting stuff - just like writing any other CGI program.

Comment: I know that, but by default Apache does not support other methods than GET and POST.

Comment: According to http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put :

<quote>There is some confusion about whether Apache supports the PUT method. In fact, Apache handles PUT exactly like it handles the POST method. That is, it supports it, but in order for it to do anything useful you need to supply a suitable CGI program. This is on contrast to the GET method, which Apache supports internally by sending back files or SSI documents. </quote>

There's further instruction for setting up a CGI script to handle HTTP methods under that link.